# Creating Hyperlink From Anchor Text

Tags: excel, rubygems

I have an excel sheet that has the URL for a ruby gem in column 1 and the gem name or anchor text in column two. Is there a way to do some type of mass process that takes the URL and creates a hyperlink out of the anchor text in column 2?

Comment: Have you looked at the syntax for `hyperlink`[Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313)

Comment: no that looks like a good start

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it in bulk though so I can do it for thousands of cells at once

Comment: Let's assume that you have a header in row 1; url in Column A, Anchor text in Column B. In cell "C2", enter this `=hyperlink(A2,B2)`. Now copy that cell, highlight the range (just like in Excel), paste into the highlighted range - Done!. The only other type of "mass process" would be to write some code to do this, but really this is impractical - by the time you had opened the script editor and written the first line of code, you could have already copy/paste the formula into several thousand rows.